# ColorFunction and/or ColorScaling issue with ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

My goal is to use `ColorFunction` to color a cylinder based on the $z$ value of a separate `Plot3D`. I'm not sure if I am making a mathematical error somewhere or if I am just messing up some snippet of the following code.

```
a = Pi;
b = 2;
f[x_, y_] = y;
u[x_, y_, t_] = -((8 E^(-((π^2 t)/20)) (2 - π) Cos[(π y)/4])/π^2) - 
   (8 E^(-((π^2 t)/5)) (2 + 3 π) Cos[(3 π y)/4])/(9 π^2) - 
   (8 E^(-((9 π^2 t)/20)) (2 - 5 π) Cos[(5 π y)/4])/(25 π^2);

Table[ContourPlot[u[x, y, t], {x, -a, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
   Contours -> 8], {t, {0, .1, .3, .5, 1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

[image]

Now, I want to wrap each contour plot onto a cylinder by gluing the $x=-a$ edge to the $x=a$ edge; the bottom of the cylinder is then at $y=0$ and the top at $y=b$.

```
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {rho, 0, 2},  
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, theta, rho}, 
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][u[x, rho, t]]],
    Mesh -> 8, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, theta, rho}, 
    f[Cos[theta], rho]]}, ViewPoint -> {-2.3, 0.77, -2}, 
    ViewVertical -> {-0.08, 1, -0.06}], 
    {t, {0, .1, .3, .5, 1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

[image]

This is clearly not correct based on what I am after. Where am I going wrong?

I tried turning `ColorFunctionScaling` off and on with no luck. I also tried replacing that middle snippet dealing with the coloring with

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, theta, rho}, 
ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[u[Cos[theta], rho, t], {0,2}]]]
```

where a `Plot3D` shows $u(x,y,t)$ ranges over (about) $[0,2]$. I suspect the solution lies in some tweaking of this part.

Comment: Could you pls add the function `f`?

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `ColorFunction` I thought the only arguments allowed to pass to it in a `ParametricPlot3D` were x, y, z, and u where these are the three spacial variables of `ParametricPlot3D` together with the parameter variable u. Is that not correct? (I wish the documentation explained this better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the colors from the 2D contour plots and use them as the setting for `MeshShading`:

```
 tt = {0, .1, .3, .5, 1, 2, 3, 4}; 
 cps = Table[ContourPlot[u[x, y, t], {x, -a, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], Contours -> 8],  {t, tt}];
 colors = Cases[cps[[#]], _RGBColor, Infinity] & /@ Range[8];
```

Then

```
Grid[Partition[Table[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, 
       {theta, -Pi,  Pi}, {rho, 0, 2},
   Mesh -> 8,
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, theta, rho}, u[x, z, tt[[i]]]]},
   MeshShading -> colors[[i]],
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, theta, rho},
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"][u[x, z, tt[[i]]]]],
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], {i, Range[8]}], 4]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer too since I did not know how to pull the colors of a `ContourPlot` to then use as `MeshShading`.

Answer (score 5):

Main thing to know is that for `ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f[x]]` you must have `0 < f < 1`. What `ColorFunctionScaling` does - it rescales range `x`, and you need to rescale domain `f`.

I will consider a simplified case of your problem and you can generalize. Let's take **t = 0.5** Stripping your function **u** of unneeded variables, you have:

```
u[y_,t_]=(-8*(2 - Pi)*Cos[(Pi*y)/4])/(E^((Pi^2*t)/20)*Pi^2) - 
 (8*(2 + 3*Pi)*Cos[(3*Pi*y)/4])/(9*E^((Pi^2*t)/5)*Pi^2) - 
 (8*(2 - 5*Pi)*Cos[(5*Pi*y)/4])/(25*E^((9*Pi^2*t)/20)*Pi^2)
```

Let's plot its original and re-scaled forms:

```
{min, max} = {NMinValue[#, y], NMaxValue[#, y]} &@{u[y, .5], 0 < y < 2}
```

> {1.29488*10^-16, 0.789722}

```
Plot[{u[z, .5], (u[z, .5] - min)/(max - min)}, {z, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> 0]
```

[image: plot of original and rescaled coloring function]

You can see the difference. Now, the correct cylinder for **t = 0.5** is set up like this - and you can see exact correspondence to your rectangle pictures:

```
GraphicsRow[{

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], z}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0, 2}, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, m, n}, 
             ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[u[z, .5], {min, max}]]], 
Mesh -> 8,  MeshFunctions -> 
     Function[{x, y, z, m, n}, Rescale[u[z, .5], {min, max}]]],

  ContourPlot[u[y, .5], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], Contours -> 8]}]
```

[image: properly colored cylinder with contour plot]

Comment: `NMaxValue[]` might be more convenient to use here... also `Rescale[]`.

Comment: @J.M. `NMaxValue` - yes, but not sure about `Rescale` - it acts on lists, not functions. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Something like `ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[u[z, 0.5], {0, max}]]` was what I used.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, this makes sense, updated.

Answer (score 3):

I figured that since the question's been answered anyway, I'd illustrate the `Texture[]` alternative, which completely avoids the rigamarole of having to find the extrema of the coloring function:

```
a = π; b = 2;
f[x_, y_] := y;
u[x_, y_, t_] := -((8 E^(-((π^2 t)/20)) (2 - π) Cos[(π y)/4])/π^2) -
                 (8 E^(-((π^2 t)/5)) (2 + 3 π) Cos[(3 π y)/4])/(9 π^2) -
                 (8 E^(-((9 π^2 t)/20)) (2 - 5 π) Cos[(5 π y)/4])/(25 π^2);

tex = With[{t = 0.5},
           Image[ContourPlot[u[x, y, t], {x, -a, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
                             AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
                             Contours -> 8, Frame -> None, ImagePadding -> None, 
                             PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
                 ImageResolution -> 256]];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], ρ}, {θ, -a, a}, {ρ, 0, b},
                 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
                 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[tex], 
                 ViewPoint -> {-2.3, 0.77, -2}, ViewVertical -> {-0.08, 1, -0.06}]
```

[image: cylinder with texture]

I'll leave the generalization as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Very nice. I too like that it avoids the extrema issue.