# Applying an ArrayPlot as a texture to the surface of a cylinder

Tags: textures

I would like to apply a matrix plot to the surface of a 3D cylinder. The matrix plot is the output from a custom cellular-automata, and it would be nice to see the lefthand side of the plot connected to the righthand side.

#### Edit

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
mrt =
  ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100], 30],
    Frame -> False,
    ImagePadding -> 0,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0];
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t]/2Pi, Cos[t]/2Pi,u},{t,0,2Pi},{u,0,2},
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  ImageSize -> {300, 300},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  PlotStyle -> Texture[mrt],
  Mesh -> None,
  ViewPoint -> {0, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to call this a duplicate of [On coloring the faces of a surface differently with parameter-dependent colors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/343/245) because all the methods are covered there (except for how to draw a cylinder).

Comment: As kguler has pointed out in the answer the principle of "Wrapping a rectangle to form a cylinder" has also been answered, sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the raster image produced by `MatrixPlot` as `Texture` directive if you construct `Cylinder` using `ParametricPlot3D` or `ContourPlot3D`.

```
 mplt = MatrixPlot[Table[Sin[x y/100], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> 0, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

#### **ParametricPlot3D**

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {rho, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], Texture[mplt]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #3} &), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

[image]

**Update:** To wrap the matrix plot around the cylinder

Change the setting for `TextureCoordinateFunction` to

```
TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)  (*Thanks: @Rahul *)
```

[image]

Or leave out the `TextureCoordinate...` options out and use `PlotStyle -> Texture[mplt]` (thanks: @DROP TABLE):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta], rho}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {rho, 0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Texture[mplt], Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

#### **ContourPlot3D**

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], Texture[mplt]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #3} &)]
```

[image]

#### Related:

[How to Texturize Disk/Circle/Rectangle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7657/125)

[Heike's answer MathGroup: Texture on Disk in Mathematica 8](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Nov/msg00582.html)

[Wraping a Rectangle to Form a Cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14828/125)

[ColorFunction and ColorFunctionScaling Issue with ParametricPLot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14721/125)

Comment: Thanks this looks great exactly what I was looking for. Great Idea to use a parametric plot instead of Graphics Primitive.

Comment: It looks like you're projecting the texture on the $(x,z)$ coordinates, while I think the OP wants it to wrap around the cylinder along $(\theta,\rho)$. For the parametric plot, that would be `TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)`.

Comment: The given answer by kguler did not exactly answer my question since the texture is duplicated, however the answer and the link to "Wraping a Rectangle to Form a Cylinder" have solved my problem. I ended up using:   ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t]/2 Pi, Cos[t]/2 Pi, u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 
  2}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[mrt], Mesh -> None]

Comment: @Rahul, right, thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 12):

I made a program of this kind before and the most efficient solution I found was `Cuboid`. Or perhaps it was the best-looking solution. The rendering code is:

```
render[stack_, iterations_, color_, thickness_, overlap_] := Module[
    {center, interval, width = Length[stack[[1]]]},
    interval = 2. \[Pi]/width;

    Last@Reap[Do[
      Sow[Rotate[
        Last@Reap[Do[
           If[stack[[level, rad]] == 1,

            center = {Cos[interval*rad]/interval, 
               Sin[interval*rad]/interval, 0} // N;

            Sow[Cuboid[
              center + {0, 0, -level} + {thickness, overlap/2 + .52, .52}, 
              center + {0, 0, -level} - {0, overlap/2 + .52, .52}], color];
            (*make the cylinder darker on the inside*)
            Sow[Cuboid[
              center + {0, 0, -level} + {0, overlap/2 + .52, .52}, 
              center + {0, 0, -level} - {.02, overlap/2 + .52, .52}], 
             Darker[color, .5]]],
           {level, 1, iterations}], _, {#1, #2} &],
        interval*rad, {0, 0, 1}, center]]

      , {rad, 1, width}]]
   ];
```

It just goes through the matrix, and if there is a 1 it `Sow`s the proper `Cuboid`. Note the `Rotate`, which rotates an entire column's worth of cells (columns are parameterized by `rad`).

The renderings look like:

[image]

By changing `thickness` you can also render the blocks as wafers to get a nice cylindrical look.

Comment: Wow. This looks awesome!

Answer (score 4):

I have an implementation of something like this. I might as well post it.

- The cylinder is made up of square polygons.
- `coordinates` lists all the corners of all the polygons at a certain height.
- `layer` takes the coordinates of the corners and generates the polygon required for one row in the cylinder.
- `pieces` generates all the rows.

Code:

```
coordinates[z_, n_, h_] := Riffle[
  Append[z] /@ CirclePoints[n],
  Append[z + h] /@ CirclePoints[n]
  ]

layer[n_, z_, data_] := GraphicsComplex[
  coordinates[z, n, 2 Pi/n],
  Polygon[# + {0, 1, 3, 2} /. {(2 n + 1) -> 1, (2 n + 2) -> 2}] & /@ 
   Pick[Range[1, 2 n, 2], data, 1]
  ]

pieces[n_, nrOfLayers_] := MapThread[
  layer[n, #, #2] &, {
    2 Pi Range[nrOfLayers]/n,
   Most@CellularAutomaton[30, RandomChoice[{0, 1}, n], nrOfLayers]
   }]

Graphics3D[
 pieces[200, 50],
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

Example output:
[image: Example]

Different colors can be given for the inside and the outside:

```
Graphics3D[{
  FaceForm[Blue, Yellow],
  pieces[200, 50]
  },
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think I recall a question along these lines in the last few days. Did that one end up getting closed as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @MarcoB not yet: [83112](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83112/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I suspect that might happen soon then ;-) This whole series of answers fits that question very closely.

Comment: @MarcoB I think so, and +1 @ Pickett :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ArrayPlot[]`, one might want to use `Image[]` directly to produce the textures. For instance, here is the CA texture:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            ca30 = CellularAutomaton[30, RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100], 30];]

(* Image[]'s convention is the reverse of ArrayPlot[]'s *)
tex = Image[1 - ca30, ImageSize -> Large];

ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[u], 2 Sin[u], z}, {u, -π, π}, {z, 0, 2},
                 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
                 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[tex]]
```

[image: CA on a cylinder]

Here's a colorful example:

```
tex2 = Colorize[Image[Rescale[
        N[Table[Sin[π x/10 + Sin[π y/10]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 40}]]], ImageSize -> Large],
                ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], z}, {u, -π, π}, {z, 0, 2}, 
                 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
                 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[tex2]]
```

[image: colorful sine on a cylinder]