# Mapping Images in Parisian metro stations

Tags: image-processing

One particular aspect of some Parisian metro stations is that stations' walls are curved, even in the sides where one would place advertising posters. Here is a picture of one such station:

[image: A train station in Paris]

I was told that the posters must be mapped to the surface of the walls in such a manner that they appear undeformed to a person standing on the opposite platform. ( My opinion is that they don't actually bother doing this, or maybe the mapping is so subtle that I can't notice it.)

Say the station's ceiling follows a half ellipse centered at $(0,0)$, with major (horizontal) axis $a$ and minor (vertical) axis $b$. And the posters start a position 0 vertically and never exceed a vertical position c (therefore $c<b$). What would such map look like ? And how to properly transform the image in *Mathematica* given that map.  Here is an image to play with the mapping, a woman alone laughing at a salad,

[image: woman with salad]

This is what advertising looks like, right ?

One should be able to do this with `ImageTransformation`, and the map might be simpler than I imagine, and not an elliptic integral. As a side (optional) question, Can you make a dynamic demonstration of this effect, with `Graphics3D` ? ohh and can you think of an image that would look almost unrecognizable once mapped ?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26268/5478

Comment: @Kuba Yeah Looks like the same question just for a different surface. Should I delete it  ?

Comment: it is a nice question, I would leave it. Maybe just close it and leave the links.

Comment: Why are women always laughing when they salad? http://thehairpin.com/2011/01/women-laughing-alone-with-salad