# Plotting an NDEigensystem solution over a helicoid

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot the solutions of a particular Hamiltonian eigensystem over a helicoid. In other words, my solutions are a function of the radial variables (r,$\phi$). The Helicoid is given by the parametrization: (r cos(a$\phi$), r sin(a$\phi$), $\phi$).

How do I display the solutions over the Helicoid as a heatmap or something? The problem with Plot3D is that it treats the variables as (x,y) coordinates. Does RegionFunction help in this case?

The solutions are of the form {funs,vals} where funs is the list of all the eigenfunctions.

Comment: Related: [Applying an ArrayPlot as a texture to the surface of a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/applying-an-arrayplot-as-a-texture-to-the-surface-of-a-cylinder)

Comment: @C.E. Thank you, you're awesome.